DataRow Boolean Error - Specified cast is not valid
I have conditional logic that checks two DataRows
foreach (DataRow dr in dtClients.Rows)
{
   if (Convert.ToBoolean(dr["NewClient"]) == true && dr["ClientStatus"].ToString().Equals("Sign Up"))
   {
       // do stuff
   }
}

The dtClients is populated from the database. In my local dev environment, this code works as expected but on my UAT environment it is deployed to, I receive the error "Specified cast is not valid." And the stack trace leads right to the if() statement above.
I've checked the appropriate table and the columns that the above code refer to are the same (BIT and VARCHAR(15)) on my local vs UAT. I cannot for the life of me figure out why I am getting an error on one environment but not another.
Any suggestions?

Have you already tried to put these two conversions into separate variables?
This makes it easy to debug which causes the issue.
Also for simple string comparisons I prefer to use the == operator (if culture-aware comparison is not needed).

It feels like the error would be on Convert.ToBoolean for null values, but that would be a different error. I can;t see why dr["ClientStatus"] would fail a cast since you call ToString() on it.

The only way you can get "cast" error here is when dr["NewClient"] return DBNull
object _b = DBNull.Value;
Convert.ToBoolean(_b);

// Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.

If you have byte or bool in dr["NewClient"] you wouldn't have this error.
byte? _b = null;
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBoolean(_b));

Hence, try doing this
 Convert.ToBoolean((dr["NewClient"] == DBNull.Value ? "false" : dr["NewClient"]))

